# Get path where i used the Context Menu

Tags: windows, batch-file, contextmenu, explorer

I want to add an option to the Win10 Context Menu, which executes a batch file in the folder where I right-clicked. I created a Key for this in Regedit under `"\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell"` and a subkey `command`. Under the `command` Key I added the command `cmd /c "start C:\Users\me\Documents\bat\file.bat"`. This works fine, but it only executes the batch file in `C:\Users\me\Documents\bat\` but I want it to execute the batch file in the folder where I right-clicked. I thought of copying the batch file to the folder where I want to execute it first, but I don't know how to get the path.

Comment: Why do you want to copy your bat file instead of changing the working directory by executing `cd clicked_folder`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To execute your bat file in a directory, you dont have to copy it there, you can change the working directory.

Change your registry command to:

```
cmd /c "start C:\Users\me\Documents\bat\file.bat %w"
```

This will pass the menu folder as argument to your batch file.
Add directory change at start of your bat file:

```
cd /d %1
```

Comment: what if I want to pass selected file full path to the batch??
%w sends current selected directory.

Comment: %V gives the selected file full path :)

Answer (score 0):

If you enter the following at the Command Prompt:

```sh
%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Add "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\Run file.bat\command" /VE /D "%ComSpec% /D /C \"Start \"\" /D \"%V\" \"%UserProfile%\Documents\bat\file.bat\"\"" /F
```

It should create a context menu entry for you, which should do as you've asked. i.e. create an entry which should look something like this:

```sh
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /D /C "Start "" /D "%V" "C:\Users\me\Documents\bat\file.bat""
```

When you right click in the background of your Explorer Window, you should see a context menu entry named `Run file.bat`, which should run your script `file.bat`, located in your `\Documents\bat\` directory, and with the cuurrent working directory as that which you clicked in the background of.

**There is absolutely no need to make changes to the content of `file.bat`**

Please note that as the file was clearly located within your own profile, and because you shouldn't really be creating context menu entries for every user on your system, I used HKEY_CURRENT_USER as the root key for the data. If you really do have a need to add the entry to for all users, and want to still create it from cmd.exe, ensure your cmd.exe instance is 'Run as administrator', and change `HKCU` to `HKLM`. *Please also note that you should not add entries directly in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, as that is really just mapped from other locations, The appropriate locations are HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes, as offered above*.

Comment: mhickey, I have noticed that you have returned as logged into this site but have not responded to this answer, which was created after you had accepted an answer already. I would appreciate it if you could try this alternative method, and provide appropriate feedback. Thank you.